# iPhone - Rejected for not using HTTP Live Streaming protocol

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, appstore-approval

My first application got rejected for not using the HTTP Live Streaming Protocol.

Ok, now I have done some reading, and apparently I need to re-encode with Apples 'HTTP Live Streaming Tools' my videos into various files so it can be streamed.
So am I correct, that I don't have to change anything in my binary/code to refresh my app or is there a real "protocol" in iOS which I have to implement or is this all server side.

Also I only have 'static' videos and no real stream, so all I need is the mediafilesegmenter, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend utilizing a service called [Encoding.com](http://www.encoding.com/). They offer a really great service that will take your MOV's and convert them to on demand adaptive iphone streaming versions which you can then call from your app. So all your app will need to do is call your new .m3u8 adaptive streaming file rather than the MOV.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, the way I do is I get the URLs of the movies from an external XML file, so I reencoded and cut my files into 10sec pieces 4 times in different bitrates and changed the URLs in my XML. Hoping that they won't find another excuse for rejecting me.

Comment: How come you can click to accept the answer, but you can't be bothered to upvote it?